# spring integration data-redis and data-jpa version compare my project data-redis and data-jpa version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration, spring-data-redis

In a project developed with Spring boot 1.5.7, data-redis and data-jpa was used. Data-jpa version is 1.11.7, data-redis version is 1.8.7. I need to add spring-integration to the project. I will use version 4.3.12.  data-jpa version in this version is 1.10.10, data-redis version is 1.7.10.

It is not the same as the data-redis and data-jpa versions used in the project.

What problems can this cause ?

Answer (score 0):

That can't cause any problem as far as you don't override any dependencies provided by Spring Boot. You really should just rely on the well-tested composition of dependencies represented in Spring Boot. Even if Spring Integration `4.3.12` brings Spring Data JPA `1.10.10` as a transitive dependency that doesn't mean that it is not overridden by Spring Boot.

I'm not sure which do to point you out, but one of the main goals in Spring Boot is to bring into the target project consistency and cross-compatibility in the dependencies part.

This might help you a bit: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management